# sparkR: verify number functioning worker nodes

Tags: sparkr

After starting a spark-ec2 cluster, I start sparkR from /root with

```
$ ./spark/bin/sparkR
```

A few lines of the resulting message include:

```
16/11/20 10:13:51 WARN SparkConf: 
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES was detected (set to '1').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --num-executors to specify the number of executors
 - Or set SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES
 - spark.executor.instances to configure the number of instances in the spark config.
```

So, following that suggestion I added the last line to spark-defaults.conf

```
$ pwd
/root/spark/conf
$ cat spark-defaults.conf
spark.executor.memory   512m
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /root/ephemeral-hdfs/lib/native/
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /root/ephemeral-hdfs/conf
spark.executor.instances 2
```

This resulted in the message no longer being printed.

In sparkR, how can I verify the number of worker nodes that will be accessed?

Comment: Can you share the Spark Configuration parameters you are using?

Comment: OK, I added the line as suggested to spark-defaults.conf

Answer (score 0):

After you start your spark cluster you can check your current workers and executer on spark ui on Master_IP:8080 for example in local its localhost:8080
And you can also check that your configuration will correctly apply in localhost:4040 under environment tab

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks and I see that now. Can that info, and perhaps the number of cores, also be accessed from within sparkR?

Comment: you can assign number of core using configuration 'spark.executor.cores' and by default it will use all core of ur machine